# Breakpoint isn't breaking

Tags: cocoa

Trying my hand at Mac Cocoa for the first time. Lion and XCode 4.1.

My little app is supposed to save a date and a task. I'm using 2 buttons, a scroll view, and an array controller. One button is for adding, the other for deleting.

The add button has no effect, and execution doesn't stop at a breakpoint in the handler. I know it's a broad question, but can anyone point me at what to look at? I think it's all wired correctly, but obviously not.

Comment: please post code so we can narrow down the issue

Comment: The current version of Xcode is 4.2.1, and it brings some significant improvements over 4.1, the biggest of which is support for ARC in the compiler. You should update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you actually connected your buttons to an action, either on a specific desired target or on the First Responder.

Comment: How do I show the code? I tried copying the .m file and pasting it into a text editor, but no joy. It seems the button isn't connected, but it has an IBActoin method in the .m file, and an entry in the .h file. It's linked to the array controller, and the action is add. I hope I'm using the correct terminology.

Comment: @Mike: There is no code for an outlet connection. Just right-click on the controller and verify that the correct action has the button hooked up to it. If it isn't connected, drag from the action to the button to connect it. (Also, if you want to connect the button to the array controller's `add:` action, then what .h and .m are you referring to?)

Comment: Peter, I'm sorry, I'm floundering in a pool of unfamiliar terminology. The array controller shows (under Received Actions) both the add and delete buttons. Is that the controller you're talking about? The code I'm referring to is in the testappAppDelegate.h and testappAppDelegate.m files.

Comment: @Mike: The controller I'm talking about is whatever controller you want the button to send its action to. If that's the array controller, then yes. There's no need to involve the application's delegate.

Comment: XCode (afaik) added the methods into the delegate. The array controller is supposed to save to an XML file (default??), but isn't. I'd actually prefer a SQLite db. So if the delegate isn't involved, how does one step thru the code, which at this point is probably less important than just having it work.

Comment: @Mike: Xcode would have added action methods to the delegate if and only if you connected the button to the delegate by dragging from the target to the relevant place in the delegate's code. So, do you mean to connect it to the app delegate or to the array controller? As for XML vs. SQLite, that's outside the scope of this question; you should ask another question about that.

Comment: I think it should be connected to the controller.... I'm getting this from a book that's supposed to be an Xcode tutorial. I'll have to read that chapter again. How would I un-hook it from either?

Comment: @Mike: Click the X next to the button's “Sent Action”. You don't need to do this if you're changing what the button is connected to, because it can only be connected to one thing, so connecting it to thing B will necessarily disconnect it from thing A.

Comment: Peter - I upgraded XCode, and the source for the app we were discussing got scrambled. I dumped it and started all over again, very carefully did it like the book, and it still doesn't work. In main.m: on the line return_NSApplicationMain(argc,(const_char **)argv); "Thread1 Program received signal 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'. If you're getting tired of this, tell me and we'll quit.

Comment: @Mike: The crash is somewhere else; you can safely assume that line is not the cause of the crash. You should ask a separate question about that, though.

Comment: OK, and thanks for sticking to it. Off to start a new thread.